# Mongo export query escaping special character

Tags: mongodb

I am running the following Mongo export query in Ubunty 16.04 terminal.

```
mongoexport --host host_mongos.gigs.com -uthyu -prtyu --db tco --collection warehouse --query '{$and:[{"brand":"Levi's"},{"docType":"style"}]}' --type=csv --fields style,ean,status --out Data.csv
```

I am not getting any output.
Seems I have an error with escaping the special character in Levi's.
Tried Levi\'s, "\"Levi's\"", "Levi*", etc . But still in vain.

Comment: What about ``/^Levi/``? That's using a regular expression, and as long as your argument to `--query` is wrapped with `''` then that should be okay.

Comment: Hi Neil, I am not getting output for ^Levi's also.